# Sublime Text 2 HTML default markups?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, markup

Sorry for asking such basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

How can I get ST2 to write the basic html markup structure in new files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Emmet package.](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet)

---

**Installation**

The simplest method of installing Emmet (and any other package) is via the Package Control package. To install that, follow the instructions from the [project's home page](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2):

> The simplest method of installation is through the Sublime Text console. The console is accessed via the ctrl+` shortcut or the View > Show Console menu. Once open, paste the appropriate Python code for your version of Sublime Text into the console.

```
import urllib2,os,hashlib; h = '2915d1851351e5ee549c20394736b442' + '8bc59f460fa1548d1514676163dafc88'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) if dh == h else None; print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h) if dh != h else 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')
```

Next, open the command palette using the shortcut: CTRL + SHIFT + P
and type: "install package" and press Enter.

Type "Emmet" and select: Emmet (ex-Zen coding) for Sublime Text package.

And that’s it. After selecting the package, Emmet will install. You'll get a notification once it's done.

---

**Use**

Emmet allows you to type CSS-like expressions that can be dynamically parsed to produce (amongst other things) HTML.

For example, open a new file, type `html:5`, then press Ctrl + E. This will expand into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Emmet can do a lot more though, for example `ul>li*3` will expand to:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I would recommend that you watch the [getting started video](http://emmet.io/) and check out [the docs](http://docs.emmet.io/). Integrating Emmet into your workflow is a real time saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DefaultFileType`.

If you have the `Package Control` package installed, you can install `DefaultFileType` from inside Sublime Text itself. Open the `Command Palette` and select "`Package Control: Install Package`", then search for `DefaultFileType` and you're done!

`Package Control`: https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2